# In a class of 32, each boy knows 5 girls and each girl knows 8 boys. Determine the number of girls in the class.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Is this problem wrong? (as in, unsolvable)

Call $B$ the set of boys and $G$ the set of girls in the class. Say there are $m$ boys, and there are $n$ girls. We are also assuming that if a boy knows a girl then the girl must know the boy. We can call $S$ the subset of $B \times G$ of the boy-girl pairs who know each other in the class. We can easily work out that $|S| = 5|B| = 5m$ and $|S| = 8|G| = 8n$ so we have the following set of equations:
\begin{align}
5m - 8n & = 0 \\
m + n & = 32
\end{align}
By solving these we get hat $n = 13/160$ which is definitely **not** a whole number. Is there some part of the process I'm doing wrong or is the problem simply impossible to solve with whole numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this solvable, we have to acknowledge non-binaries and replace the second equality with $m+n\le 32$ (i.e., $m+n+d=32$).
This allows the solutions

- $m=n=0$, $d=32$.
- $m=8$, $n=5$, $d=19$.
- $m=16$, $n=10$, $d=4$.

Comment: Who are the "non-binaries"?

Comment: @user https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-binary_gender

Comment: Should that last line read 'd = 6' rather than 'd = 4'? With d = 4, the sum is only 30, not 32.